# C# Metro App UI update

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, microsoft-metro

My problem is just the same as **this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540260/c-sharp-winrt-update-ui-from-thread)**.

I am working on the new WinRT for **Metro Applications in C#**(win8 release preview). 
The problem is:  My app My program runs **a thread in the background** which receives messages from the server(In fact, I ported  a XMPP client app). Some information should be updated in the UI.

I have tried that link. The second method seems would work for me, but I has found **there is no Dispatcher.Invoke(...)** in the VS2012RC intellisense which means there is no this extension method.

After searching carefully, I think maybe **this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931453/metro-ui-update)** can help me. But I have no idea how to start with my application in this scenario (since I am a beginner in C#).

Can you give me some advice? I would appreciate if you show some code snippet that would help me so much.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your UI thread run :

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Windows.UI.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
```

Then from your background thread call the `RunAsync` function in the `dispatcher` variable you just created.

```
dispatcher.RunAsync(DispatcherPriority.Normal, <delegate to run on UI thread>);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579027/run-code-on-ui-thread-in-winrt).

Comment: I think should use CoreDispatcherPriority instead of DispatcherPriority.