# Custom Search on objects in Metro / Modern UI

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, asp.net-4.5

I'm implementing an application for Windows 8. It will search a quite large number of data from xml.

So for now I'm using a text box and list view to show the search results, but when i use the textbox event TextChanged is slows down the typeing, because it executes a new search for each letter typed.

So the question is, how to in metro / modern ui make a delay, to trigger the event after few letters are typed, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create your own Search experience.  You should hook into the SearchPane and handle it there.

```
SearchPane searchPane = SearchPane.GetForCurrentView();
searchPane.QuerySubmitted += searchPane_QuerySubmitted;
searchPane.SuggestionsRequested += searchPane_SuggestionsRequested;
```

You can then handle the events as necessary in the handlers.  If you are providing suggestions and you have a slow running process that will by async, you msut get a deferral.

```
void searchPane_SuggestionsRequested(SearchPane sender, SearchPaneSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
    // do real time type ahead here
    deferral.Complete();
}

void searchPane_QuerySubmitted(SearchPane sender, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    // complete search here
}
```

Comment: Okay this works way better, kinda sad that it has to go through charm and can't to this with a normal textbox. But it will do. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Could you update this with the new recommendations involving the `SearchBox` control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are discouraged from running anything that might bog down the UI as a synchronous task.  Try running it as a background task which updates the UI on completion.  See [Background Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx) and [TimeTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) for more information.  On task completion use the [Core Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher)  to update the UI.  [Core Dispatcher example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990152/c-sharp-metro-app-ui-update)

Comment: Excellent! This is what I needed. I think i will go with this and the charm, also it will be useful for the rest of the application. Big thanks! Sadly I can't accept two answers :(

Comment: Can't I have to have 15 reputation to do that. I sill miss 10.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the "Leave" event instead of the text changed event of a text box? Would make it a lot smoother and would be when the user has finished their input inside the text box.

Comment: It more intuitive to just type, type & leave won't do.
Also I want some sort suggestions when the user starts typing.