# How do i use backgroundworker with timer and progressBar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a timer tick event that it's interval set to 10000

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Update();
}
```

In Update i have:

```
public int Update()
{
    counter += 1;
    int position = (int)Math.Round((counter / updateTime) * 100);
    xpProgressBar1.Text = counter.ToString() + " %";
    xpProgressBar1.Position = counter;
    if (counter == 10)
    {
        DownloadingHtml();
        ScrollNews();
        counter = 0;
    }
    return position;
}
```

Then in the backgroundworker do work:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int position = NewsUpdate();
    object param = "report";
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(position, param);
}
```

And the backgroundworker progress event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{

    xpProgressBar1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %";
    xpProgressBar1.Position = e.ProgressPercentage;
    if (counter == 10)
    {
        DownloadingHtml();
        ScrollNews();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

What i want to do in the first step is that the Update method will be called each 10 seconds but through the backgroundworker.

In the second step i want to add to the backgroundworker another method:

```
public void ScrollNews()
{
    label3.Text = SaveOldHtml.HtmlLoadedFileNumber.ToString();
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.myList);
    richTextBox1.SelectAll();
    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    richTextBox1.Text = combindedString;
    scrollerText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.myListWithoutLinks);
    scroller1.TextToScroll = scrollerText;
    if (NewsLevels.newsLevel && NewsLevels.shouldStart)
    {
        scroller1.Start();
        NewsLevels.shouldStart = false;
    }
    if (NewsLevels.newsLevel == false && NewsLevels.shouldStart)
    {
        scroller1.Start();
        NewsLevels.shouldStart = false;
    }
    string[] rlines = richTextBox1.Lines;
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = rlines[0].Length;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    richTextBox1.Select(rlines[0].Length, rlines[1].Length + 1);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
}
```

The ScrollNews method is being called from the Update method and it's updating richTextBox1 and Scroller1 with text.

And in the end i want to add the last method in Update:

```
private void DownloadingHtml()
{           
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
        page = webClient.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
    }            
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
    w.Write(page);
    w.Close();
    page = @"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html";
    listsext.Ext(page);
    count++;
}
```

All this methods i want to be working from the backgroundworker.

In the form1 constructor i did that first it will call the DownloadingHtml method once then call the ScrollNews method once then activate the backgroundworker and then start the timer1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are misusing `BackgroundWorker` class. It is usually used to perform a single time-consuming action that should not block th UI. All time consuming operations should take place in `OnDoWork` event that is executed on a separate thread. Report progress is executed on UI thread and is used to update progress bar and other UI elements that show progress.

`timer1_Tick` is executed on the UI thread and blocks your UI while executing. It's not a good idea to perform any downloading or processing there if you don't want your UI to hang.
You could start TPL `Task`, `Thread` or just start BackgroundWorker anew in every `timer1_Tick` execution. This `Task` or `Thread` can then report progress and update current UI state, calling form's thread-safe methods. `BackgroundWorker` can use it's own `ReportProgress` mechanism for this purpose.

In case of using separate Task or Thread, each method called from a separate thread should check Form's `InvokeRequired` and call `BeginInvoke` to perform thread-safe UI update. This is described well here: [beginInvoke, GUI and thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268250/begininvoke-gui-and-thread) and in many other similar questions.